# Cross Platform Quranic Software with Translations

Tags: quran, software

I want to read Quran on my computer and smartphone.

I need Quranic software which is:

1. Cross platform: Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, iOS systems.
2. Have (Sahih) translations to: English, Français, Español, Deutsch, Italiano, Português, Dutch, Bosanski, Shqiptar, Swedish, Türkçe, Русский, Indonesia, Melayu etc.
3. Have Recitations such as: Sheikh Al-Menshawy, Sheikh Abdullbaset, Sheikh Al-Husari, Sheikh Saad Al-Gamdi, Sheikh Mishari Al-efasi etc.
4. Quran texts in Uthmani formats.

Copy/Past Ayats and translations of Quran features.

Comment: Is this question even on-topic?

Comment: in my opinion no. I answered to my question because I want to help for peoples who want to know true islam and don't know arabic language and want to read Quran.

Answer (score 2):

As-salamu alaykum:

Quranic Software [KSU - Electronic Mosshaf project](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/) "**Ayat**"

**Ayat** is a cross platform Quranic software with unique features, translated to many languages. currently installed on more 1,000,000 PC world wide.

Project also provides a [mobile interface](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/m.php) , a [desktop program "Ayat"](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/ayat/) , an [Android App "Ayat"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sa.edu.ksu.Ayat&safe=on) , an [iOS App "Ayat"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id634325420), a [Facebook App](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/fb) and a [Twitter App](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tw)

Download link for all versions: http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/ayat/?l=en

**Ayat Quranic software translated to many languages**:

English - Sahih International

Français - Hamidullah

Español - Abdel Ghani Navio

Deutsch - Bubenheim & Elyas

Italiano - Piccardo

Português - El Hayek

Dutch - Sofian Siregar

Bosanski - Korkut

Shqiptar - Efendi Nahi

Swedish - Bernström

Türkçe - Diyanet Isleri

Русский - Кулиев

Indonesia - Bahasa Indonesia

Melayu - Basmeih

كوردى - برهان محمد أمين

فارسى - حسین تاجی گله داری

اردو - جالندربرى

Malayalam - Abdul Hameed and Kunhi

বাংলা ভাষা - মুহিউদ্দীন খান

தமிழ் - ஜான் டிரஸ்ட்

ภาษาไทย - ภาษาไทย

Somali - Abduh

Hausa - Gumi

Swahili - Al-Barwani

Uzbek - Мухаммад Содик

中国语文 - Ma Jian

**Ayat Quranic software has many Tafsir**:

Indonesian - Tafsir Jalalayn

русский - Russian - Кулиев -ас-Саади

عربــي - Arabian - ,السعدي, البغوي, ابن كثير, القرطبي, الطبري

**Quran Recitations**:

Sheikh Al-Huthaify

Sheikh Saad Al-Gamdi

Sheikh Al-Menshawy

Sheikh Abdullbaset

Sheikh Al-Husari

Sheikh Mishari Al-efasi

Khalefa Al-Tunaiji (Teacher)

More Recitations.

**Quran texts**: Uthmani formats.

**Ayat is a cross platform Quranic software with unique features such is**:

Copying ayats and translations of Quran

**and other features**.

Answer (score 1):

There is another app which is [Islam360](http://theislam360.com) which is available on [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/islam-360/id1006098149?mt=8), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.islam360&hl=en), [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/islam-360-universal/9wzdncrd89dv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).  It Also has nice features like searchable in Arabic, English, Urdu.  Translation in English, Urdu, Roman Urdu, Nepali, and Marathi totally 10 translations. Tafseers and all six books of Hadiths with translation.

Answer (score 0):

https://qurandb.com

Except for being cross-platform (it runs on Windows), it has all the Translations, Reciters, and Mushaf texts you need. It also has verse-wise Tafseer, Shan-e-Nazool, and related Ahadith.